# List custom post type and highlight currently visited item

Tags: php, css, wordpress

I have a custom post type called 'product'. On each product page I would like to have a sidebar with all products listed. The current product in the sidebar should be underlined.

When visiting product 3 for example, product 3 should be highlighted:

> Sidebar 
> Product 1
>  Product 2
>   **Product 3**
>  Product 4

I figured a solution could be a wp-menu containing all products and then use .current-menu-item class to achieve the highlighting. But the sidebar has to be updated automatically when new products are created.

Below is my way of listing all products. Is there a way of integrating a .current-menu-item functionality?

```
<?php $loop = new WP_Query( array( 'post_type' => 'product' ) ); ?>
<?php while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post(); ?>

<a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a>

<?php endwhile; ?>
```

By adding a class like this?

```
<a class="current-product" href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there is an easy way to achieve this.

Here is a modified version of the code that does your thing:

```
<?php 
// get the current product ID
$current_post_id = get_the_ID();

$loop = new WP_Query( array( 'post_type' => 'product' ) );
while ( $loop->have_posts() ) {
    $loop->the_post(); 
    ?>
    <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" <?php echo get_the_ID() == $current_post_id ? 'class="current-product"' : ''; ?>><?php the_title(); ?></a>
    <?php 
}
?>
```

Here we basically save the ID of the current product in a variable, and then for each product of the list we check if the looped product ID is equal to the current product ID. And if it is, we display the `class="current-product"` attribute.